# Cant use full storage of 1tb ssd

Tags: boot-partition

[image: screenshot of the Disks tool]

I don't know much, but my guess is that I created a partition of 50GB of 1TB but there  is still 950GB left. How do I use the 950GB? Do I create a new partition to use the 950GB?

Will it erase the data in the 50GB partition?

Comment: If you have clean partition in 950gb, you can create new partition, and just use it. It won't affect the 50gb partition

Comment: You can also expand the 50 GB partition into (some or all of) the free space if desired.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506846/edit) and add more information about your computer and how you are using this disk, as well as how you want to use it in the future. Also add information about the distro and version of Linux you are using. If you want to use the whole disk with Ubuntu, the easiest would be to expand `/dev/nvme0n1p2` to fill up the "Free Space". See [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) for more.

Comment: You can expand /, you can move /home to new partition, or you can use a data partition or two for some larger amounts of data. Or combinations of any of those. As with any major change, always have good backups. [Move Home](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455822&p=14010437#post14010437 If you create data partition(s), you have to give yourself ownership & permissions to use it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting , It does not have to be another drive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a new partition. No, that shouldn't affect the existing one (but it is always good to back up your data before making *any* change to a disk). Think of your disk as a library. If you have built a new library, that library might have a lot of space, but you cannot use that space until you have added some shelves to store books. Similarly, you can't use your disk until you create a partition and format (this creates a filesystem) it.

You have installed a few shelves (one, small partition) so that's the only part of your "library" (disk) you can use. To use the remaining, empty space, you need to add shelves, to make a new partition and then format it to the desired filesystem, most likely ext4.

So, use the tool in the screenshot, and create a new partition taking as much of the space as you want it to use, and then you will be able to store things in that partition.